# Topological Quantum Computation Resources Prerequisite

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, quantum-computer, topology, ising-model

I am about to start my BSc Theoretical Physics project on Topological Quantum Computation.
I have studied the basics of quantum mechanics, condensed matter phys, statistical mechanics.
Are there any introductory texts / resources anyone can recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Steve Simon from Oxford has got great lecture notes on the subject: https://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/SteveSimon/oxfordtopquantum2016.html

Answer (score -1):

Instead of a book (actually the start of the art is not so advanced), I would suggest this article http://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.2337825?journalCode=pto and obviously the bibliography related.

I think that *pure* topological state are very hard to be numerically simulated (In particular:**what's the goal?**), but many body systems are unavoidable if you are trying to get into this marvellous theoretical field.

**Ising model, Heisenbeg model** and many others are well approximating systems that are studied in depth and are right now one of the most hottest area of theoretica/computational physics, mostly due to its strict connections with Neural Networks and machine deep-learning algorithms.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will have a look at the article